# Build Asp.Net website project using Azure Devops

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I am trying to build a solution using CI pipeline. It is an old ASP.NET Web Forms Site. The yaml file is as follows

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'PublishBuildArtifacts'
```

After build nothing is copied to artifact 'PublishBuildArtifacts' and I see a message "Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'PublishBuildArtifacts'."
My understanding is that via PackageLocation property the package would be in artifactstagingdirectory folder which should be published in the next step. What am I missing here? Do I need to use copyfile task? If so what would be the source and target folders? Thanks

Comment: How do you get the ,sln file in your 'ASP.NET WEBSITE' i also have website project wcshich dont have solution and project file. when check with developer they told me, for website we dont have any solution or project file.. So i really dont know how to build it...Please feel free to answer for the [below question by me

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76216606/how-to-deploy-the-tfvc-asp-net-website-code-to-the-azure-app-services-using-azu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add [CopyFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task before `PublishBuildArtifacts` task :

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(agent.builddirectory)'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'PublishBuildArtifacts'
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great.

Comment: Please look the below question which posted by me and guide me. Thanks!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76216606/how-to-deploy-the-tfvc-asp-net-website-code-to-the-azure-app-services-using-azu